# How to get req data from nextjs middleware function to page component?

Tags: next.js

I successfully write a middleware function in nextjs

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { ip, geo } = req
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/'
}
```

Here in this middleware function, I am getting `geo` object and `ip` string. In the `geo` object it has `country`, `city`, `latitude`, `longitude`, and `region` field. Now I have to get this data into my home page component.

```
import type { NextPage, GetServerSideProps } from "next"

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      dfd
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  console.log(context);
  return { props: {} }
}
```

How can I get those middleware data like `ip`, `geo` in my page component.

Comment: You either pass them as cookies or query parameters from the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

@Md Ali
if you deploy your application in vercel  you will get ip and geo.

Comment: Yes, I know. My question is how can I access those data from page component.

Comment: I have to sent this data to backend on button click.

Comment: From middleware you can't access data.in  middleware you  store in cookies. 

retrieve cookie data in page component.